# Javascript button did not work if i scroll the page / elements from page messes up if i resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

So, first of all i have a webpage with the "Parallax" effect, that effect with scrolling pages.

I have 2 problems:

1) I have a button that shows/hides a menu bar with javascript.

```
$(".show").click(function(){

    $("nav").fadeToggle();
});
```

The button works perfectly till i scroll the page. At this moment it stops working. I have the button position fixed so i want it to be always on the screen. And the menu bar fades in/out when i scroll. So when i scroll down to the next page i want to have that button to show/hide the menu, but it doesn't work. It works only when the page is scrolled all the way top.

2) Today i tried to open my project on another computer with a monitor with a lower resolution, and i noticed that everything is messed up. As messed up as when i try to resize the window if you know what i mean. The elements from the first page goes down to the seconds.. and so on. How can i solve this problem?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/238870_q1e05Ar.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax1 {
  background-image: url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/eiffel-tower-wallpaper-18_fRZLW4V.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax2 {
  background-image: url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/eWtfMME_jJm8t1k.png');
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax3 {
  background-image: url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers-89_FxDoTt7.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax4 {
  background-image: url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/pexels-photo_vF03DpP.jpeg');
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax5 {
  background-image: url('http://www.uniwallpaper.com/static/images/Sunset-Village-Wallpaper_8I7ogbf.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 36px;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #ffffff 25%, #ffffff 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  margin: 17px auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: fixed;
  align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 30));
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

body,
html,
.main {
  height: 100%;
}

.text1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
}

.p1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.style1 {}

.style2 {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.style3 {}

.style4 {}

.style5 {}

button {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  border: none;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 26px;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.htmljscss {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.textbackground {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 150px;
}

.textbackgroundbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 30), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 30));
}

.dropbtn {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 160px;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 700px;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Make sure that padding behaves as expected */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Container for skill bars */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  background-color: #ddd;
  /* Grey background */
}

.skills {
  text-align: right;
  /* Right-align text */
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* Add some right padding */
  line-height: 30px;
  /* Set the line-height to center the text inside the skill bar, and to expand the height of the container */
  color: white;
  /* White text color */
}

.html {
  width: 70%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #34e893, #0f3443);
}


/* Green */

.css {
  width: 70%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000046, #1cb5e0);
}


/* Blue */

.js {
  width: 45%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #cb356b, #bd3f32);
}


/* Red */

.php {
  width: 30%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #141e30, #243b55);
}


/* Dark Grey */

.skillbars {
  width: 550px;
  height: 350px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 603px;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 
 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Add smooth scrolling to all links
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {

      // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
      if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({

          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top

        }, 800, function() {

          // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
          window.location.hash = hash;

        });
      } // End if
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {



    $(".show").click(function() {

      $("nav").fadeToggle();
    });
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('.hidescroll').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('.hidescroll').fadeIn();
    }
  });

  var images = new Array()
  images[0] = "../images/html5.png";
  images[1] = "../images/javascript.png";
  images[2] = "../images/css.png";
  setInterval("changeImage()", 900);
  var x = 0;

  function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById("img").src = images[x]
    x++;
    if (images.length == x) {
      x = 0;
    }
  }



  /* When the user clicks on the button,
   toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
  function myFunction(eleId, event) {
    //
    // stop event propagation in order to avoid the window.onclick execution
    //
    event.stopPropagation();
    //
    // remove show class to previous shown div
    //
    document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content.show').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
      ele.classList.remove("show");
    });
    //
    // select by id using the param value
    //
    document.getElementById(eleId).classList.toggle("show");
  }

  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    //
    // if not a button and not a dropdown-content....
    //
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') && event.target.closest('.dropdown-content') == null) {
      //
      // remove show class to previous shown div
      //
      document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content.show').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        ele.classList.remove("show");
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<style>
  #draggable {
    width: 1px;
    float: right;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  body,
  html,
  .main {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  section {
    min-height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="hidescroll">

    <nav>



      <ul>

        <li>

          <a href="#section1" class="hide">Multiplayer online battle arena</a>

        </li>

        <li>

          <a href="#section2" class="hide">League of Legends</a>

        </li>

        <li>

          <a href="#section3" class="hide">Defence of the Ancients 2</a>

        </li>

        <li>

          <a href="#section4" class="hide">Riot</a>

        </li>

        <li>

          <a href="#section5" class="hide">Valve</a>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </nav>

  </div>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="fixed"><button class="show"> Show menu</button></div>


    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">

      <div class="htmljscss">

        <img id="img" width="110px" height="160px" src="../images/html5.png">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="skillbars">
      <p class="p1">HTML</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills html">70%</div>
      </div>

      <p class="p1">CSS</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills css">70%</div>
      </div>

      <p class="p1">JavaScript</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills js">45%</div>
      </div>

      <p class="p1">PHP</p>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="skills php">30%</div>
      </div>



    </div>
    <div class="textbackground">
      <div class="textbackgroundbar">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1', event)" class="dropbtn">Despre mine</button>
          <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown2', event)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
          <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown3', event)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown3</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
        <p class="p1">
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">a</a>
        <a href="#about">b</a>
        <a href="#contact">c</a>
      </div>
      <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">asda</a>
        <a href="#about">asdasd</a>
        <a href="#contact">adasda</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>














  <div class="parallax1">
    <div class="main" id="section1">
      <section class="style1">
        <div class="text1">
          <p class="p1">Multiplayer online battle arena (MOBA), cunoscut ca și strategie și acțiune în timp real este un sub gen al jocurilor video de strategie în timp real, în care jucătorul controlează un singur caracter din una dintre cele două echipe. Obiectivul
            este distrugerea structurilor inamice cu ajutorul unităților generate periodic care au drum prestabilit. Jucătorii au în general abilități și avantaje variabile care se îmbunătățesc odată cu trecerea timpului și care contribuie la strategia
            echipei per ansamblu. MOBA este o fuziune între un joc de acțiune și un joc de strategie în timp real, jucătorii nu pot construii clădiri sau unități.</p>

          <p class="p1">Genul a pornit cu Aeon of Strife (AoS) o hartă personalizată pentru StarCraft unde patru jucători fiecare controlând o singură unitate puternică și asistați de unități mai slabe controlate de computer sunt puși împotriva unei echipe mai puternice
            controlată de computer.</p>

          <p class="p1">Defense of the Ancients (DotA), este o hartă bazată pe Aeon of Strife pentru Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos și The Frozen Throne. DotA a fost primul titlu major al genului și primul MOBA în care au fost organizate turnee sponsorizate.</p>

          <p class="p1">DotA a stat la baza jocurilor League of Legends și Heroes of Newerth, urmând o continuare: Dota 2.</p>

          <p class="p1">Blizzard Entertainment anunțând deja că lucrează la propriul MOBA - Heroes of the Storm</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>









  </div>
  <div class="parallax2">
    <div class="main" id="section2">
      <section class="style2">

        <!--azirrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Azir.jpg" alt="Azir" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Azir.jpg" alt="Azir" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Azir</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--fizzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Fizz.jpg" alt="Fizz" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Fizz.jpg" alt="Fizz" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Fizz</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--zedddddddddddddddddddddddd-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Zed.jpg" alt="Zed" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Zed.jpg" alt="Zed" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Zed</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--dianaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Diana.jpg" alt="Diana" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Diana.jpg" alt="Diana" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Diana</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--katarinaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Project Katarina.jpg" alt="Katarina" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Project Katarina.jpg" alt="Katarina" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Katarina</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Yasuooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Yasuo.jpg" alt="Yasuo" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Yasuo.jpg" alt="Yasuo" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Yasuo</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Leblancccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Leblanc.jpg" alt="Leblanc" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Leblanc.jpg" alt="Leblanc" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Leblanc</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Taaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaalon-->
        <div class="dropdown">

          <img src="../images/Talon.jpg" alt="Talon" width="200" height="100">
          <div class="dropdown-content1">
            <img src="../images/Talon.jpg" alt="Talon" width="829" height="400">
            <div class="desc">Talon</div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="parallax3">
    <div class="main" id="section3">
      <section class="style3"></section>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="parallax4">
    <div class="main" id="section4">
      <section class="style4"></section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax5">
    <div class="main" id="section5">
      <section class="style5"></section>
    </div>
  </div>





  <div class="parallax"></div>
```

Ok, i put here my entire code and i added some random images so u can make an ideea about it. 
Maybe a lot of things are wrong and messed up here, BUT i'm just a beginner, so please take me easy.

Thank you a lot for your time spent reading all this. I know it's a lot.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english, i'm still learning it.

Comment: did you try running your code snippet? It is all sorts of buggered up.

Comment: Yes i tried. The "show menu" button from top left corner is bugged because... i don't know, i have no ideea why it doesn't works. In my notepad, it works. And the javascript thing in the right top corner which is a function that changes images after an interval, and is not that important... I post my code so you can see how my page messes up when you resize the window..